# FileNotFoundException though canRead() and exists() returns true

Tags: java, file, exception, filereader

I do this and write some content to this file.

```
fileSymbol = new File("D:\\TempFiles\\SymbolFile.xml");
fileSymbol.createNewFile();
prSymbol = new PrintWriter(fileSymbol);
while(//condition goes here){
   prSymbol.write(text);
}
```

Then I try to read from this file as,

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader(fileSymbol);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
String line = br.readLine();
```

When I try to run, it gives the following exception

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: fileSymbol (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

When I try

```
fileSymbol.canRead();
fileSymbol.exists();
```

returns true for both.

I do not understand why I get this error though I have already created the file. When I check the location manually, I am able to see my created file.

PS: I have just provided the code snippet of my code.

Comment: Have you closed `prSymbol`? It may be holding a lock to the file.

Comment: @Vulcan Yes. I have closed it before accessing it for reading like prSymbol.close();

Comment: Not a duplicate. That question refers to a compile error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: fileSymbol (The system cannot find the file specified)

That message, if you have transcribed it accurately, can only mean that you are using `"fileSymbol"` as the file name, where previously you were using `"D:\\TempFiles\\SymbolFile.xml"`.

NB calling `createNewFile()` the line before you create an output stream or writer to the same file is a complete waste of time.

Answer (score 4):

Add the following before you read the file

```
  prSymbol.close();
```

It is not required to call flush() before close .Reference [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html#close%28%29) - close()

Comment: Don't `flush()` before `close()`. It's redundant. It's like saying `return` after `throw` except that java won't compile that.

Comment: @AdrianPronk - yes I just looked it up at the docs.Will update my answer

Comment: I have closed the PrintWriter like prSymbol.close(); before accessing it with this FileReader.

Comment: @Abi You can see for yourself that posting non-trivial bits of code in comments is completely illegible and therefore a waste of time. Edit it into your post. There are several further redundancies in this code. You don't need to call `createNewFile()`, and initializing something to null and assigning it on the very next line is poor practice. You could use a single line for both.